# What does """ if((counter & (1 << j)) > 0): """ do?

Tags: python, python-3.x, if-statement, data-structures, set

I am trying to print all subsets of an array. I came across this `if` statement in one of the solutions.

What does this `if` condition do?

```
if((counter & (1 << j)) > 0):
```

Comment: How do we know without knowing what is `counter`, `i` and `j` ?  `<<` is bitwise left shift operator [doc](https://python-reference.readthedocs.io/en/latest/docs/operators/bitwise_left_shift.html).

Comment: It checks if bit number `j` in `counter` is set.

Comment: This was the program I was referrring to:https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/power-set/

Answer (score 5):

Your statement:

```
if ( (counter & (1 << j)) > 0 ):
```

It's some bitwise operations. Let's break it down:

- `(1 << j)` generates the number `0b1` and shifts it left by `j` places - `j` must be an integer. This is akin to saying `2**j`, or 2 to the `j`th power, but doing it with the bit-shifting operator `<<` makes it clear we're doing bitwise operations.
- `counter & (1 << j)` takes the result of that last operation, and does a bitwise `and` with the variable `counter`. It seems that `j` is a specifier for a bitmask - it tells which bit is important to check in in `counter`. Since whatever `(1 << j)` produces will only have one `1` in its binary representation, the expression `counter & (1 << j)` will always produce either a power of 2, or 0.
- `> 0` checks if the number that was produced was 0.

All in all, this is a fairly involved way to check if the `j`th bit from the right in `counter` is equal to `1` or `0`. Without seeing the rest of your code, it's impossible to tell what the line does in context, but hopefully this gives you enough of a hint to whatever you're trying to figure out.

Comment: This was the program I was referrring to:https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/power-set/

Answer (score 1):

The & operator is a bitwise operator. More information [here](https://wiki.python.org/moin/BitwiseOperators).

Basically, if we consider counter as a binary:

```
counter = 0b0010
1 << j -> with j = 0
```

j will be the position that you want to evaluate with the 1.

Therefore, in this case the IF statement will not be executed because the AND operator will return 0.

But with:

```
counter = 0b0010
1 << j -> with j = 1
```

The IF statement will be executed because the AND operator will return 1.

To understand a little more, you can play with the following piece of code and change the values of counter and j:

```
counter = 0b0100
j = 2

if((counter & (1 << j)) > 0):
    print("True")
else:
    print("False")
```